How to link a dockerized gazebo server with a MacOS host gazebo gui?
I have an Apple Silicon (M2) Macbook Pro, running MacOS Sonoma.
On this, I run a docker container which is running some combination of ROS 2 nodes, which are connected to a simulation in Gazebo Harmonic.
I am able to view the gazebo output through x11 forwarding, but it is very computationally expensive and slow to load, which is why I want to try to find a better alternative.
I also have Gazebo Harmonic installed the host Mac machine.
Would it be possible to somehow run the gazebo server in the docker container with no display output, and instead forward this to the gazebo gui on the MacOS host? My idea is that it would render it on my native machine instead of inefficiently having to forward the rendered output from the docker container.
I read some things about using gazebo environment variables to connect over a network (or something like gazebo transport?) but wasn't able to implement them myself as the documentation looks limited.
